# List all dates and check passed date

Tags: php, date, if-statement

Example (Today is **13.05.2013**):

> 11/05/2013,**20/05/2013**,9/05/2013 <-- false;
>
> 10/03/2013,14/04/2013,**12/05/2013** <-- true;
>
> **15/06/2013**,11/06/2013,8/06/2013 <-- false;
>
> **13/05/2013**,10/04/2013,02/05/2013 <-- false (is today = false)

**PHP :**

```
function outdate($dates) {
    $dates = str_replace('/','-',$dates);
    $dates = explode(',',$dates);
    $today = time();
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        if($today > strtotime($date)) {
            // ????
        }
    }
}
```

I have done with some parts. Please help me to do **return** `true` or `false`

I will use my function like..

```
if( outdate('11/05/2013, 12/05/2013, 9/05/2013') ) {
  // do something
}
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: I dont understand the problem? You don't know how to `return true`? After you've just written it in the question?

Comment: @F4r-20 If dont know how to check if max date is passed

Comment: When it should return true? If all dates are in past? If some dates are in past? If no dates in past?

Comment: @FAngel If max date (highest date) is passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose this is what you need:

```
function outdate($dates) {
    $res = true;
    $dates = str_replace('/','-',$dates);
    $dates = explode(',',$dates);
    $today = time();
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        if($today < strtotime($date)) {
           $res = false;
           break;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

It will return true if all passed dates are in past. And false if at least one date is today or in future.

Comment: `if(outdate('13/05/2013'))` is true so it's fail (Today will return false)

Comment: @l2aelba I just reverted initial condition  (where `$today > strtotime($date)`). You may simply leave `$today < strtotime($date)` if date equal to today's date should return true.

Comment: expand pls :( what is gonne be ?

Comment: + Can you update you anwser ? If max date = today will return false;

Comment: @l2aelba You may edit other's answers if you see something wrong there. JFYI.

Answer (score 2):

```
function outdate($dates) {
$flag = false;
$dates = str_replace('/','-',$dates);
$dates = explode(',',$dates);
$today = time();
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    if($today > strtotime($date)) {
        $flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
return $flag;
}
```

Comment: How about is Today isn't out to date ?

Comment: It depends on you, if you want it to be out of date or not. currently it doesnt include today as out of date. you can add "=" if u want to return true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array instead, something like this (untested)

```
 $array = array("11/05/2013", "12/05/2013", "9/05/2013");

$result = checkDates($array);

function checkDates($array)
{

  foreach($array as $a)
  {
    $date = strtotime(preg_replace("/^([0-9]{1,2})[\/\. -]+([0-9]{1,2})[\/\. -]+([0-9]{1,4})/", "\\2/\\1/\\3", $a));

    if($date>time()) return false;

  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my another to do.. Just find a max date first then check it!

```
function outdate($dates) {
    $dates = str_replace('/','-',$dates);
    $dates = explode(',',$dates);
    $ts_dates = array();
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $ts_dates[] = strtotime($date);
    }

    $max_date = max($ts_dates);
    $today = strtotime('today');
    if($max_date < $today) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work. But why do you need to find max date at all? All suggested solutions will simply check all dates. And return true if all of them are in past. If all are in past - than max is in past. If max is in past - all are in past. Your solution is good because it implicitly checks if max date is in past, but you do additional work by searching max date when it is not needed. That is just a hint for you to think about.

Comment: I using your , But my code is what I think to do before asked here :P thnkas :D @FAngel